# NSPredicate Filtering with special characters

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nspredicate

I am using the code below to filter the array using the predicate.

```
self.aPredicateString = [self.aPredicateString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ contains[cd] '%@'", self.selectedSearchParameter, self.searchString]];


NSLog(@"Predicate string %@",self.aPredicateString);
        self.aPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:self.aPredicateString];
```

If user enters either `\` or `'` the code crashes with error.

I do not understand what the mistake is? Either special characters are not allowed in `NSPredicate` or should I format the predicate in different way.

Comment: I don't think you should have the single quotes around the %@ because that turns it into a literal

Comment: Could you provide the crash report?

Answer (score 7):

I wonder, why you use all this `self.aPredicateString stringByAppendingString`, but I think, your predicate should look like this:

```
self.aPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ contains[cd] %@", self.selectedSearchParameter, self.searchString]];
```

with no `''` around the `%@`

Comment: self.aPredicateString = [self.aPredicateString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" AND %@ contains[cd] '%@'", self.selectedSearchParameter, self.searchString]];                                                        The actual statement I am using looks like this. I need to append the string to the existing string and form the predicate. Before AND in the statement there is one more predicate condition I am using.

Comment: I have even tried without quotes. Even that crashed the application.@rdelmar

Comment: did you found a solution?